# How to set system wide environment variables in mac high sierra

Tags: macos, environment-variables, macos-sierra

I know environment variables can be set for the terminal app using:

`vim ~/.bash_profile`

`export <variable> <value>`

Since adding environment variables to `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` or `/etc/launchd.conf` is no longer supported.

Also, `launchctl setenv <variable> <value>` doesn't work.

Comment: This https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146047 worked for me.

Comment: Did you find the solution?  I'm trying to do the same.